# How do I open the COM port specified by user?

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

I am trying to open the COM port that is given by the user input. I have tried the following code and the error message "Error in opening serial port" is printed.

```
int main()
{
    BOOL Status;
    HANDLE ComPort;
    char* ptr;
    char str[] = {'\\','\\','\\','\\','.','\\','\\','C','O','M','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
    printf("Enter COM Port: ");
    ptr = str + 10;
    fgets(ptr,4,stdin);
    size_t len = strlen(str);
if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == '\n') {
  str[--len] = '\0';
}
    ComPort = CreateFile((const char*)str,                //port name
                      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, //Read/Write
                      0,                            // No Sharing
                      NULL,                         // No Security
                      OPEN_EXISTING,// Open existing port only
                      0,            // Non Overlapped I/O
                      NULL);        // Null for Comm Devices

  if (ComPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
      printf("Error in opening serial port");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
  else{
      printf("opening serial port successful");
  }
 .....
 ...
```

So what is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: First try running as administrator. You may not have permissions to open the port otherwise.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk I am running it on codeblocks

Comment: `char str[] = {'\\','\\','\\','\\','.','\\','\\','C','O','M','\0','\0','\0','\0'};` is same as `char str[] = {"\\\\\\\\.\\\\COM\0\0\0"};`. Yet I think you want `"\\\\.\\COM\0\0\0"` and other later offset adjustments.

Comment: You may need to run codeblocks by right clicking and doing a run as administrator.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have corrected my code to account for this and I have run  codeblocks as administrator but I still get an error

Comment: dilinex, "I still get an error" is uninformative.  Exactly what was the error?  Same as before?  What was the input, What was expected?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The code executes the command printf("Error in opening serial port"); instead of  printf("opening serial port successful");

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I included the prefix so that I could account for ports larger than 10.

Comment: 3x What was the input?  Do you want prefix \\.\ or \\\\.\\ ?

Comment: The input I am using is 5.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix `'\\','\\','\\','\\','.','\\','\\'` is wrong.  See ["\\.\COM10"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/115831/howto-specify-serial-ports-larger-than-com9)

Original code failed to handle reading the `'\n'`.

Read a line and then form the com port name.

```
//char* ptr;
//char str[] = {'\\','\\','\\','\\','.','\\','\\','C','O','M','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
//ptr = str + 10;
//fgets(ptr,4,stdin);
//ComPort = CreateFile((const char*)str,  

char buffer[80]; // be generous
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential \n

char str[sizeof buffer + 7] =  "\\\\.\\COM";  // Use correct prefix
strcpy(str, buffer);
...
```